# MathJax removes all body content in UIWebView

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, uiwebview, mathjax

I'm trying to make a class method that will take a MathJax string, wrap the required HTML around it and load it into a specified UIWebView. My code is below:

```
+ (void)loadMathJax:(NSString *)jax inWebView:(UIWebView *)webView fontSize:(int)fontSize
{
    NSString *mathJaxPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"MathJax" ofType:@"js" inDirectory:@"MathJax"];

    NSString *htmlContent = [NSString stringWithFormat:@""
                             @"<html><head>"
                             @"<meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1.0' />"
                             @"<style type='text/css'>"
                             @"body { background-color:transparent; font-size:%d; color: black; }"
                             @"</style>"
                             @"<script type='text/javascript' src='%@?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML-full'>"
                             @"</head>"
                             @"<body>\\(%@\\)</body>"
                             @"</html>"
                             , fontSize, mathJaxPath, jax];

    NSLog(@"%@",htmlContent);

   [webView loadHTMLString:htmlContent baseURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:mathJaxPath]];
}
```

If I use this method, the NSLog shows the correct HTML (e.g. with `<body>\(Z_1 = 4 + 2i\)</body>`), but the web view in the simulator is blank. Using the Safari web inspector shows that everything has been removed from between the `<body>` tags.

Things I have tried:

- Use the MathJax CDN instead of loading it locally. No difference.
- Replace the `\\(%@\\)` with `test text` (i.e. remove the MathJax tags). Still no content between `<body>` tags on running of app.
- Remove the MathJax `<script>` call. Text now shows up but not rendered as mathematics.
- Change `baseURL:` from the mathJaxPath to `nil`. No difference.

Comment: First, figure out if it's a problem with the web view or the html. Use a simple hello world `htmlContent` and see if it works.

Comment: @duci9y The problem definitely seems to be related to the MathJax library. Replacing `htmlContent` with a simple hello world works fine. Like in my 3rd bullet point of things I've tried, if the MathJax library isn't loaded, the HTML renders properly.

Comment: The `baseURL` should be the directory the MathJAX script is located in, and `mathJaxPath` should simply be the name of the script file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked it out. I forgot the closing `</script>` tag for the MathJax import.